# Ubuntu Terminal 16.05LTS How do I keep progress bar output on same line when I resize terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, printing, output

For some applications that prints output on the same line (carriage return) such as `wget` or anything that has a progress bar overwriting the previous progress, when I resize the terminal window or change the position on the screen the output starts to print on a new line every second and scrolls down continuously until the process completes 100% or the progress bar reaches 100%.

For example:

```
Epoch 0   [Train |                    |    1/20000 batches, 1.86 co
Epoch 0   [Train |                    |    2/20000 batches, 4.65 co
Epoch 0   [Train |                    |    3/20000 batches, 3.10 co  
Epoch 0   [Train |                    |    4/20000 batches, 5.32 co
```

What I want is an overriding input like this:

```
Epoch 0   [Train |                    |    4/20000 batches, 5.32 co
```

If I do not resize, the output overwrites the current line and does not scroll down. I would like to be able to resize my terminal while keeping such output on the same line (as it was intended).

This problem is not present with `wget` running directly on the terminal, but as I recall when calling it via a C program or a Python program, a re-scroll will trigger this and the output will continuously print on a new line.

This is problematic when I want to keep some previous output visible on screen for presentation purposes for example. I tried resizing my terminal and positioning it *before* running my Python script, and the problem still occurs.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?